# select * or individual columns

Tags: t-sql

Is there any difference in performance between

```
select *
from table name
```

and

```
select [col1]
      ,[col2]
       ......
      ,[coln]
from table name
```

Comment: But from a reliability / maintainability standpoint, there's a **HUGE** difference - I would argue you should **NEVER** use `SELECT *` in your production code. What if the table structure suddenly changes - a column is dropped or two BLOBs are added..... I would argue you should **ALWAYS** explicitly specify your columns that you want ..

Answer (score 5):

It is a SQL **antipattern** to use `SELECT *`. It is faster for the database when you specify columns (it doesn't have to look them up) and more importantly, you should not ever specify more columns than you actually need. If you have a join in your query you have at least one column you don't need (the join column) and thus `SELECT *` is always slower to return records in a query with a join since it is returning more infomation than necessary.

Now all this sounds like a small improvement and in a small system it might be, but as the database grows and gets busy, the performance implications become bigger. There is no excuse for using `SELECT *`.

`SELECT *` is also bad for maintenance especially if you use it to insert records - always specify both the columns you are inserting to and the fields from the select in an INSERT statement that uses a SELECT. It will break if you change the table structure. You may also end up showing the user columns you don't want them to see such as the GUID added for replication.

If you use `SELECT *` in a view (at least in SQL Server) the view will still not automatically update in the case of a change to the underlying tables. If someone gets the silly idea to re-arrange the column order in the table (yeah I know you shouldn't but people do this on occasion) using `SELECT *` might mean that data will show up in the wrong columns in reports or inserts which can cause problems where things might be misinterpreted. I can think of one case where two columns were swapped in a staging table and the social security number became the amount we intended to pay the person giving a speech. You can see how that might really muck up the accounting except we didn't use `SELECT *` so we were safe because the columns retained the same name.

I want to note that you don't even save much development time by using `SELECT *`. It takes me a max of about 15 seconds more to use the table names even in a large table as I drag them over from the object browser in SQL Server (you can get all the columns in one step).

Comment: I really believe that the special case of `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM…)` should be mentioned in this otherwise thorough answer.

Comment: I'd rather not steal the attention away from your answer, but in certain exceptions a `SELECT *` can be used. Exceptions confirm the rule of course. One such case where I use `SELECT *` is when constructing a version table for objects on a specific date, constructed from logs. This is required for reporting to official authorities. In that case, I start off with a creating a temporary table that is a mimic of the original table, created by `SELECT * INTO #intm_tbl FROM object_table WHERE 1=0;` and then proceed to `INSERT INTO #intm_tbl SELECT * FROM (...)`.

Comment: [Continued] That way I don't have to change those procedures each time the object tables change. Anyway, as I said, just an exception.

Comment: @TT., Yes there a few acceptable uses of Select *. There is reason why it is in the language. However, the vast majority of the time, it should be avoided.  To create temporary information is usually not a problem. However to avoid changing sps can often create problems as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004225/insert-select-instead-of-one-column/41005609#41005609

Answer (score -1):

I suppose select * takes a few cpu cycles less since sql server parses your statements, but i don't think it will make a noticable difference

Comment: No- actually the contrary - it will take **more** cycles since SQL Server must first consult the data dictionary to find your columns in your table....

Comment: You're right, i completely forgot column definitions need to be gathered first.